# Which files need to be changed after uploading Magento store from localhost to online

Tags: magento-2.1, windows10

[image]I am a newbie
I installed Magento on my local server XAMP in Windows 10.
But then came to know THAT Magento does not support Windows OS 
Also Kindly guide me on which files include the URL which needs to be changed and also guides me on how to use the composer?

Comment: no file contains the url info there are 2 ways to change URL 
1. Via admin
2. Via DB : table core_config_data there are 2 entries that needs to be update secure_baseurl, unsecure_baseurl

Comment: https://prnt.sc/qla2ja                                                                                                          Then Why am I able to see this screen? Is it because of Windows OS

Comment: check your console you will find errors of js and css which can be resolved by static-content deploy cammand.. yes better to use ubuntu or create a linux virtual environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you in developer mode?

`php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`

Then try running:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static:content:deploy -f
php bin/magento c:f
```

If this doesn't help try checking your logs in var/log/ for errors.

As for files to edit after you upload to live check your app/etc/env.php and make sure you have correct paths/database details.